# Maximum area of projection of cuboid onto plane

Tags: mathematical-optimization, computational-geometry

For didactic purposes I solve with Mathematica the following problem
(see [Vasilyev's box](https://kvant.ras.ru/pdf/2020/2020-08.pdf) on p. 17): when the area of
the projection of a rotating cuboid in the three-dimensional space with coordinates `x,y,z`onto
the xOy plane is maximum? (The problem has the exact symbolic answer,
but I don't know an accurate proof of that.)
I consider a concrete cuboid 1 x 3 x 2 since Mathematica (and other CASes) does not operate with
abstract geometric objects. I rotate its vertices by `EulerMatrix`. Then I find their projections,
cutting the third coordinate, and find the area of the convex hull of the projected vertices. Here is my code.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f[\[Alpha]_,\[Beta]_,\[Gamma]_]:= Area[ConvexHullMesh[Table[(EulerMatrix[{\[Alpha],\[Beta],\[Gamma]}].x)[[1;;2]], 
{x, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 2}, {0, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2}}}]]]
f[-Pi/4, Pi/3, Pi/6]
(*6.86603*)
NMaximize[{f[a, b, c],a >= -Pi && a <= Pi && b >= 0 && b <= Pi && c >= -Pi && 
c <= Pi}, {a, b, c}, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]
(*{7.,{a->-2.55692,b->1.12789,c->-0.321751}}*)
```

and a lot of error communications. To be sure,

```
NMaximize[{f[a, b, c],a >= -Pi && a <= Pi && b >= 0 && b <= Pi && c >= -Pi && 
c <= Pi}, {a, b, c}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]
(*{7., {a -> -1.73782, b -> 2.01371, c -> 0.321751}}*)
```

(a lot of error communications as a bonus) and

```
NMinimize[{f[a, b, c],a >= -Pi && a <= Pi && b >= 0 && b <= Pi && c >= -Pi && 
c <= Pi}, {a, b, c}, Method -> "RandomSearch"]
(*{2., {a -> -2.01037, b -> 1.5708, c -> 1.5708}}*)
```

The question arises: is it possible to obtain the exact solution with help of Mathematica?

Comment: Use the largest x-section? That would be diagonal length x diagonal half-length.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thank you for your interest to the question. I don't understand your comment at all. Can you elaborate it? TIA.

Comment: I don't have a proof, if that's what you are asking. Clearly it's a lower bound though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some bug in "Area". If I write my own area function, I get at least a result without crashing the kernel:

Note, the first rotation about the z axis has no effect on the area in the x/y plane and need not be maximized.

```
area[a1_, a2_ /; NumericQ[a2], a3_] := Module[{},
  cub = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0}, {1, 3, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {1, 0,
      2}, {0, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2}};
  heron[p1_, p2_, p3_] := 
   Module[{n1 = Norm[p1 - p2], n2 = Norm[p2 - p3], n3 = Norm[p3 - p1],
      s},
    s = Total[n1 + n2 + n3]/2;
    Sqrt[s (s - n1) (s - n2) (s - n3)]
    ];
  pts = ConvexHullMesh[
      Transpose[EulerMatrix[{a1, a2, a3}].Transpose@cub][[All, 
        1 ;; 2]]]["BoundaryPolygons"][[1, 1]];
  heron[First[pts], ##] & @@@ Partition[Rest@pts, 2, 1] // Total
  ]
NMaximize[area[0, a2, a3], {a2, a3}]
```

Comment: First, thank you for the valuable note "the first rotation about the z axis has no effect on the area in the x/y plane ". Second, my code does not crash any kernel. Third, I am interested in an exact answer.

Comment: @user64494 Your code _did_ crash the kernel on Windows10 Mathematica v12.1.1.0 for me starting from a blank notebook.

Comment: @flinty:The executed code in nb. file on demand through Dropbox.

Comment: @DaielHuber: However,+1.

Comment: @flinty: Exclude `f[-Pi/4, Pi/3, Pi/6]` from the code. Then after 'Beep" `NMaximize` continues its work and produces the  output attached by me and a lot of messages. However, the execution of syntactically correct code is not stable.

Comment: @DanielHuber: Likely `NMinimize` badly handles my `f[\[Alpha]_,\[Beta]_,\[Gamma]_]` because `Plot3D[f[0, b, c], {b, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {c, -Pi, Pi}]` works well.